# Can non-chiral 3D TQFTs be extended to non-orientable manifolds whereas chiral ones cannot?

Tags: manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory, unitary-fusion-category, reshetikhin-turaev, drinfeld-center

As far as I know, when talking about TQFT, one usually means TQFTs on oriented manifolds with boundary (cobordisms)

It appears to me that the Turaev-Viro-Barrett-Westbury state-sum construction can be put on an arbitrary 3-manifold with boundary (cobordism) which needs not be orientable and still yields a valid (unitary) TQFT on those 3-manifolds (cobordisms). The corresponding TQFTs (whose algebraic data is connected to the Drinfeld double of the input fusion category via the Reshetikin-Turaev construction) are said to be non-chiral.

Is that true and is it also the case that (unitary) TQFTs corresponding to modular fusion categories (via Reshetikin-Turaev) that are not Drinfeld doubles (i.e. the chiral ones) cannot be extended to non-orientable manifolds with boundary?

Comment: I'm not sure, but from the cobordism hypothesis I would have thought that non-oriented TQFTs have to contain some extra data as compared to oriented TQFTs. So one should ask which TQFTs admit this extra data (your question), but the choice of this data should matter as well.

Comment: The "extra data" would be the tensors associated to all non-orientable manifolds with boundary in addition to all orientable manifolds with boundary, right? What do you mean by "the choice of data should matter as well"? That there might be multiple ways to extend the TQFT to non-orientable manifolds?

Comment: I just realize that all TQFTs on orientable manifolds can be trivially extended to non-orientable manifolds by setting the tensors associated to those manifolds to zero. This should work as gluing two boundary parts of a non-orientable manifold again yields a non-orientable manifold and the same is true for disjoint union with a non-orientable manifold. Right?

Comment: Also I just realized that the way I intended to extend Turaev-Viro state-sums on non-orientable manifolds with boundary yields zero for all non-orientable manifolds with boundary.

Comment: In general, since orientable bordisms have a forgetful functor into non-orientable bordisms, every non-orientable TQFT yields an orientable one. But in the other direction, one, or multiple, or no possibilities might exist.

Comment: Well, in my second comment I intended to argue that "no possibilities" is actually not an option, as one can always trivially extend with zero on all non-orientable manifolds. Or is there something wrong with this argument?

Comment: I find it nontrivial to see if this works. Any cobordism that can be split on a nonorientable surface would be sent to 0. Is this always a functor?

Comment: I'd say yes: "Functor" means that disjoint union and gluing on the manifold side is equal to tensor product and index contraction on the tensor side. Now first, the disjoint union with a non-orientable manifold is always non-orientiable, which is consistent with the fact that tensor product with 0 is always 0. Second, gluing two boundary components of a non-orientable manifold always yields a non-orientable manifold, which is consistent with the fact that contracting any indices of the tensor 0 yields 0 again. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: I might be a bit thick here, but I don't find it obvious that gluing two non-orientable manifolds is always non-orientable. Why can't there be an orientable closed manifold $M = M_1 \cup_\Sigma M_2$, with $M_1$, $M_2$ and $\Sigma$ non-orientable?

Comment: For example, how about the bordism $([-1, +1] \times S^2, \phi_-\colon S^2 \to \{-1\} \times S^2, \phi_+\colon S^2 \to \{+1\} \times S^2)$, with $\phi_-$ the identity map and $\phi_+$ the orientation reversal. This bordism doesn't appear in the oriented bordism category, but it's an isomorphism (since it squares to $1_{S^2}$), hence can't be 0 (if the original TQFT wasn't 0 on $S^2$).

Comment: True, that's a subtle point: I was rather thinking about an unoriented TQFT that is restricted to orientable bordism manifolds (so oriented TQFTs that do not actually depend on the orientation, if that makes sense). The Turaev-Viro TQFTs are of such type. So in your example the manifold with boundary $I\times S^2$ as such is orientable, and if you allow choosing an orientation for each of the two $S^2$ boundary components separately, the whole bordism also can be equipped with an orientation. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Maybe you could add a precise definition of "chiral TQFT" to the question? Also, where is it proven that the Turaev-Viro(-Barrett-Westbury?) TQFT does not depend on the orientation? I always thought it does, since it can distinguish several lens spaces.

Comment: By chiral I simply mean those TQFTs that do not come from a TVBW state-sum, as is already somehow hidden in the text.

Comment: The TVBW state-sum as I know it on an oriented manifold and the manifold with the inverse orientation are related by complex conjugation. In the language I use this really means that the state sum does not depend on the orientation (though not in the conventional language, I agree). By "distinguish several lens spaces" I guess you mean that those lens spaces are oriented manifolds whose partition sum depends on the orientation? So then those two partition sums should be complex conjugates to each other. Is that the case?

Comment: Just to be sure: When you say TVBW state sum you mean a construction that takes *unitary* fusion categories as input, right?

Comment: We can restrict to unitary fusion categories here without problems, I think. As for orientation reversal, $\overline{L(p,q)} \cong L(p,p-q)$, I think. But I think in general when your 3-manifold is given by a link, you reverse the orientation of the manifold by mirroring the link (need to check whether this is really true), so the Reshetikhin-Turaev-invariant should also just complex conjugate, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: I might be saying something stupid there but: isn't that a simple consequence of unitarity of the TQFT that inversion comes along with complex conjugation? When posting this question I thought that this inversion+conjugation symmetry of the state-sum could be what physicists call "the chiral symmetry", but now it seems to me that it's nothing but unitarity of quantum mechanics...

Comment: Unitarity as in "unitary functor" for oriented TQFTs, yes.